# Bad characters in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Hi I'm editing a csv file to use in my database. From some weeks when I open it with notepad++ I'm finding a bad characters at the end that broken my file like a CR.

I.e

```
"30-APR-2014","ELCO, ELCO","ELCOCESARBAD
```

Where bad is with black background (I have activate see all characters"

Anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have the same problem. In my case, the [BAD] symbol replaces a capital-en (`N`) letter.

Comment: I solved the issue with TextFx plugin. If I run TextFx->TextFx Characters-> Zap all no printable characters to #  I solved the issue replaceing the "strange" characters with #. I hope can help you

Comment: Known issue: Data corruption upon operations like `Replace`. Solution: disable auto backup. `Settings` > `Preferences` > `Backup` > (Uncheck) `Enable session snapshot and periodic backup`

Comment: @UjjwalSingh Thanks a lot, I didn't know what was going on, That keeps Notepad++ from displaying "bad" all over the place when doing a find and replace.

Answer (score 15):

The problem can occur during operations like `Replace` where an auto-backup happens mid operation. The solution is to disable auto-backup.

`Settings` > `Preferences` > `Backup` > Uncheck `Enable session snapshot and periodic backup`

[Credit to Ujjwal Singh for the solution]

Comment: To clarify: This explains what happened to OP's text file, and how to prevent it in future, but won't recover or repair the file.